# Try Catch no error statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Try Catch in my code.  I would like to know if there is a statement that only executes when no errors are found?
Finally executes with or without error, but I don't want that...

I have this

```
Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(txtFolder.Text, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Status(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Status("Resetted", , 2000)
```

And I want the last status statement only to show if there were no errors

Comment: The body of the try block only runs as long as there are no exceptions thrown in it. You probably don't need anything else if you think about it a bit.

Comment: Simply move that Status() call after the DeleteDirectory call.

Comment: You could use a combination of IF and IF NOT statements to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something as simple as this would suffice:

```
Try 
   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(txtFolder.Text, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents) 
   Status("Resetted", , 2000) 'will only have reached here if there were NO exceptions
Catch ex As Exception 
   Status(ex.Message) 
End Try
```

Comment: Oh so as soon as there is an error in the try block, it skips to the Catch statement?

Answer (score 1):

Really you don't need a special statement

```
Try

' Code to watch for exceptions

Catch Ex as Exception

' Code to handle exception and eventually, if it is not possible
' to continue, exit from this method. There are two possibilities: 
' Return <some meaningful value to the caller if this is a function> 
' Throw -->>  **without any argument** and let the caller handle the exception
End Try

' Code here will be executed only if the first try block doesn't throw exceptions
```

A common mistake is using **Throw Ex** instead of just **Throw**. The difference is subtle but is very important. If you use **Throw Ex** you overwrite the stack trace making it difficult to find the original line of the failing code.

Comment: You'll need to emphasize that the catch block has to contain a Return statement or rethrows an exception.